# Can't attach a pdf file in gmail using Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, gmail

Cannot attach a pdf file and open it in gmail app.
The gmail app is opening, but the attached file is missing.

The code used is:

```
NSString *pdfPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyFile" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pdfPath];
NSString *pdfBase64 = [pdfData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];

NSString *gmailScheme = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"googlegmail:///co?to=&subject=&body=&attachment=%@", pdfBase64];
NSURL *gmailURL = [NSURL URLWithString:gmailScheme];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:gmailURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:gmailURL options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
}
```

Comment: Do you know for sure that the Gmail app supports the `attachment` query parameter? Do you know for sure the value is a plain base64 encoding of the data? How big is the PDF? With the resulting base64 encoding, the final URL could be far too long to be valid.

Comment: Also, why specifically target the gmail app? Why not share the file using UIActivityViewController and let the user choose what they want to do with the file?

Comment: The PDF file size is around 13KB. This file is supposed to be sent out via mail only. If the user haven't logged into the default mail app, I have a check if user uses gmail app, and if yes, I want to perform the above action. The mail is composed in gmail app without the file attached.

Comment: A 13kB attachment becomes roughly 18kB as a base64 encoded string. So you are trying to create a URL with over 18,000 characters. I just did a test on an iPhone 13 Pro running iOS 16.4.1 and it had no trouble with such a URL. I was able to decode a 16kB attachment just fine. So that's not the issue. Again, does the gmail app support the `attachment` query parameter? If so, what format does it expect?